# Display uncertainty in table using pgfplotstable, read value from file

Tags: tables, pgfplotstable

I have a text file with 2 columns. The first column is the principal value and the second column is the uncertainty. How to read and display them together in a single column in a table using pgfplotstable ?

What I have now:

```
\documentclass[varwidth,border=1pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h!]
\begin{center}
    \caption{Table caption}
    \label{table1}
    \pgfplotstabletypeset[
    display columns/0/.style={     
        column name=Voltage (\si{\volt}), % name of first column
    },        
    every head row/.style={
        before row={\toprule}, % have a rule at top
        after row={\midrule} % rule under units
    },
    every last row/.style={after row=\bottomrule}, % rule at bottom
    ]{table1.txt} % filename/path to file
\end{center}
\end{table} 

\end{document}
```

And the table1.txt contains

```
1.0000000e+01   3.4916800e-01   
2.0000000e+01   3.6918400e-01   
3.0000000e+01   3.8920000e-01   
4.0000000e+01   4.0921600e-01   
5.0000000e+01   4.2923200e-01
```

This would produce:

[image]

What I want is:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You could use Datatool instead of pgfplotstable.

[image]

```
\documentclass[varwidth,border=1pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgf}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{datatool}
\DTLsetseparator{   }
\DTLloaddb[noheader,keys={Voltage,Error}]{voltages}{test.dat}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[h!]
\begin{center}
    \caption{Table caption}
    \label{table1}
    \begin{tabular}{c}
    \toprule Voltage [\si{\volt}] 
    \DTLforeach{voltages}{\voltage=Voltage,\error=Error}
    {\DTLiffirstrow{\\ \midrule}{\\}\pgfmathprintnumber\voltage~$\pm$~\pgfmathprintnumber\error}
    \\\bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Hi @daniel. Thanks for your answer. However I encountered the following error. ! Package datatool Error: Can't assign \error : there is no key `Error' in data base `voltages'. ! ! Package PGF Math Error: Could not parse input '1.0000000e+01 3.4916800e-01' as a floating point number, sorry. The unreadable part was near '3.4916800e-01 '
..

Comment: I replaced the three spaces with commas in my file. I added \DTLsetseparator{   } to my solution, that should fix the problem.

Comment: Hi @Daniel, i tried to have a second column with also has uncertainty (the text file now has 4 column). I tried to change the following lines in the code but it doesn't work as expected.
`\DTLloaddb[noheader,keys={Voltage,Error,Voltageb,Errorb}]{voltages}{table2.txt}`

`\DTLforeach{voltages}{\voltage=Voltage,\error=Error,\voltageb=Voltageb,\errorb=Errorb}`

`{\DTLiffirstrow{\\ \midrule}{\\} \pgfmathprintnumber\voltage~$\pm$~\pgfmathprintnumber\error} & \pgfmathprintnumber\voltageb~$\pm$~\pgfmathprintnumber\errorb}`

Could you point me what's wrong with this ?

Comment: There is an } after \error which shouldn't be there. Did you add the new column to the tabular environment?

Comment: Hi @Daniel. Thanks for spotting the } mistake. Now it works.